# caxlsx / axlsx Pivot Table ignore blanks and remove totals

Tags: axlsx

Following this example:

https://github.com/caxlsx/caxlsx/blob/master/examples/pivot_table_example.md

and in my implementation I am getting the totals and blanks in the pivot tables.  Anyway to remove these?